# Strange Behaviour of Response.Write()

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC Project. In my controller I check if `ModelState` is valid and according to the result I assign a value to `IsSucceed`:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelTutucu.modelim.IsSucceed = true; 
}

return View("YaziEkle",ModelTutucu.modelim);
```

In my view I have a div with a "success" class. I have some text written by `Response.Write()` to the value of `IsSucceed`:

```
<div class="success">
    @if(Model.IsSucceed) {
        string success = "It is successfully saved.";
        Response.Write(success);
    }
</div>
```

The problem is that `success` doesn't appear in the the div. It appears at top of the page. When I do something like this:

```
<div class="success">Foo</div>
```

"Foo" appears in the div, but I cant get the same result with Response.Write, it shows strange behaviour. What is the reason of this problem? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `@` instead of `Response.Write()`. `Response.Write()` is writing before the razor is rendered and written, so that's why it comes out on top, rather than in the middle or where it should be. Using `@` makes sure that the string is rendered where it should be according to the html markup.

Like:

```
@if (Model.IsSucceed)
{
    string success = "It is successfully saved.";
    @success
}
```